# How to load Awesome-websocket library in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I tried to use awesome-websocket in Aurelia, but at loading, I got an error!

I added the dependency to package.json file :

```
"jspm": {    
  "dependencies": {
     .....
     "awesome-websocket": "npm:awesome-websocket@^0.0.25",
     .....
   },
   .....
}
```

and add import :

```
import {AweWebsocket} from 'awesome-websocket';
```

but I have this error at loading the page :

> Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages /npm/awesome-websocket@0.0.25/src/awesome-websocket.litcoffee.js
>   
> Error loading http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/awesome-websocket@0.0.25/src/awesome-websocket.litcoffee.js as "./src/awesome-websocket.litcoffee" from http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/awesome-websocket@0.0.25/index.js
>   
> Stack trace:
>   
> o@http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:4:12694
>   
> e/http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:4:13219

What is the problem ?

Any ideas ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The [awesome-websocket](https://github.com/glg/awesome-websocket/) package doesn't contain a fully compiled javascript module.  It's built with coffescript and intended to be used with browserify.  Both `jspm install npm:awesome-websocket` and `jspm install github:glg/awesome-websocket` have the same result- the installed package contains coffeescript files and a couple of js files that reference other coffeescript files.

I tried importing the file mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/glg/awesome-websocket/blob/master/README.md):

> [image: compiled]

```js
import {AwesomeWebSocket} from 'glg/awesome-websocket/test/www/js/awesome-websocket';
```

But this file also contains references to coffeescript files.

Comment: so it is not possible to use it directly, I will try another

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use this package.

Try:

`jspm install npm:awesome-websocket`

Find the `jspm_packages/npm/awesome-websocket@0.0.25` directory.

The content of `.js` files (including `src` folder) need to modify the word  `.itcoffee` to `.js`.